# How to create an openstack VM instance on a specific port using jcloud api

Tags: openstack, jclouds

I know how to create a VM instance in jCloud using ServerApi but it creates instance on any available port. I want to know how to create an instance on a given port number.
In openstack cli we use `--nic port-id` parameter to specify the port as show here:

```
$ nova boot \
--nic port-id=3c564dd5-fd45-4f61-88df-715f71667b3b \
--flavor m1.tiny \
--image fedora-20-x86_64 \
--key-name lars test0
```

How can I create server using this port-id in jClouds?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/apis/openstack-nova/src/main/java/org/jclouds/openstack/nova/v2_0/compute/options/NovaTemplateOptions.java#L694

In NovaTemplateOptions, you should be able to specify network details.